# Why raw sockets sometimes return zeros in h_source and h_dest?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

I'm experimenting with Linux raw sockets and wrote a program that just listen at default interface and read the Ethernet source and destination mac- address and the protocol number above it. The code works right with no problem I guess (I mean no bugs) but it seems like sometimes(not always) it just return zeros in both source and destination address. Otherwise the 3 fields are printed correctly. so how a packet can have these two fields as zeros. Data buffer received when this happens is (I dont know why sometimes hexes is displayed as more than 1 HEX-character):

```
    Created raw socket
            Data received length is :85
    The source Mac address is 00-00-00-00-00-00
    The destination Mac address is 00-00-00-00-00-00
    The above protocol number is 0x0800
    Data is: 00 
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    00 08 00 45 00 00 47 ffffff8d 44 40 
    00 40 11 ffffffaf 2b 7f 00 00 01 7f 
    00 00 35 ffffff8a 0e 00 35 00 33 fffffffe 
    7a ffffffe2 53 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 
    00 00 01 03 77 77 77 06 67 6f 
    6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 
    01 00 01 00 00 29 04 ffffffb0 00 00
```

The whole code is:

```
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <libnet.h>

void error_print(char* error_msg){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_msg);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}

void print_mac(char* buffer, int bytes_recieved){

    struct ethhdr* mac = (struct ethhdr* ) buffer;

    printf("The source Mac address is %.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x\n",
    mac->h_source[0], mac->h_source[1],mac->h_source[2],mac->h_source[3],mac->h_source[4],mac->h_source[5]);

    printf("The destination Mac address is %.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x\n",
    mac->h_dest[0], mac->h_dest[1], mac->h_dest[2], mac->h_dest[3], mac->h_dest[4], mac->h_dest[5]);

    printf("The above protocol number is 0x%.4x\n", ntohs(mac->h_proto));

            /*....... format recieved buffer for debugging ...........*/
    printf("Data is: ");
    for (int j=0; j < bytes_recieved; j++){
        printf("%.*x ", 2, buffer[j]);
        if ((j % 10) == 0 && j != 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        if(argc < 1)
            error_print("Incorrect Number of arguments");

        int sockfd;
        sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
        if(sockfd == -1)
            error_print("Unable to open row socket...are you root...");
        printf("Created raw socket\n");

        struct sockaddr sockaddr_details;
        u_int sock_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

        /* Now recv data */
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
        char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);     // set memory to zero since recvfrom doesnt null terminate
        int recv_size;
        recv_size = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, &sockaddr_details, &sock_len);
        if(recv_size == -1 || recv_size == 0)
            error_print("Error recieving data");
        printf("\tData received length is :%d\n",recv_size);

        /* ********************************************** */
    struct ifreq ifreq_i;
    memset(&ifreq_i,0,sizeof(ifreq_i));
    strncpy(ifreq_i.ifr_name, "wlp2s0",IFNAMSIZ-1); //giving name of Interface

    if((ioctl(sockfd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifreq_i))<0)
        printf("error in index ioctl reading\n");//getting Index Name
    else
        printf("index=%d\n",ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex);

        /* Now print ether frame header */
        print_mac(buffer, recv_size);

        close(sockfd);
        free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the whole packet when this happens so we can look at it?

Comment: @user253751. I'm sorry for the delay. I just edited the question to include new source code to print ```buffer``` and the data output when this mac-addresses got zeroed out .

Comment: okay, so it's perfectly normal except the MAC addresses are zero. Can you also find out which interface the packet came through? Look at the socket address (which is `struct sockaddr_ll`, not `struct sockaddr` - the `sll_ifindex` field is the interface number and then you can call `if_indextoname` to get the interface name.

Comment: @user253751 You are right, interface index is 0 when this happens otherwise it's seems to change from 1406166039 and -400531541 when it operates normal. which I don't know why it change, and what does it mean to have an interface 0 receiving data. I also edited source code so you can check if method used to get interface number is correct. I hope you know why all these numbers change and post an answer about it, thank's alot.

Comment: 1406166039 is not valid, something is wrong with the way you're getting the number.

Comment: @user253751 yes I made a mistake using ```ioctl``` read give me back ```3``` at all times which i guess is supposed to be ```wlp2s0```

Comment: okay, I was wondering if it was a loopback interface or something without MAC addresses. But wlp2s0 is a Wi-Fi interface which should have MAC addresses. Strange.